# What .NET 4.0 technology provides modular fix-in-flight (hotswap) REST service hosting?

Tags: wcf, rest, iis-7, was, hotswap

So, it's a dream of many years now, but hope springs eternal. Is there a framework/service (WCF/WAS/MVC/ETC) that allows you to add/update services with minimal impact on ongoing requests or "sibling" services.

The dream looks something like this:

- **IIS7**

  - *Pluggable REST Service Host*

    - Shared resources (repositories, qa)
    - Service A - Dropped in folder in production, provides new REST methods
    - Service B - Updated "in flight" to fix a bug, minimal interruption of requests

I think the answer might involve WAS or possibly AppFabric (the dream isn't cautious) but since I've never managed to find an easy way to make it work, I welcome your input on how to best achieve what I think our PHP comrades just "do".

Comment: I think this is a good question.  HotSwap, and more completely, JRebel do this in the Java environment.  Java is also compiled.  I'm interested to know if there have been any advances in this field for .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEF + self hosted WCF with WebHttpBinding. Or MEF with HttpListener. The new WCF Http stack at http://wcf.codeplex.com will make this much easier in the future

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the other responses, but it's always better to get an answer to the question, much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that this is answer to the question. Question was about IIS, WCF, REST. In self hosting you will lose all IIS features and infrastructure. What is even worse you lose AspNetCompatibility which is really helpful (for example caching) when developing REST services in WCF 4.

Comment: @Ladislav  Actually the question was not about IIS.  IIS was just suggested as one potential solution.  IIS brings as many problems as it brings solutions.  The particular scenario defines whether or not IIS is actually worth it.

Comment: Is there a good reference example you might now of showing MEF+HttpListener? I'm guessing that one is "IIS Hosted" or is that WAS?

Comment: @James HttpListener does not need either IIS or WAS.  I'm not aware of any examples that use MEF in this way, but it is completely feasible.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really a REST question - it's a HTTP server question.

In the past, what I've done is to deploy a new version of an application to a new location on the server, perhaps using a URL only visible internally. I then have simply switched the IIS properties to point to the new URL.

Comment: That's cool, but since my target is creating/updating REST services I'm hoping for a framework that tends that way. So if WAS/WCF or something allows you do "compose" a REST service from many individual and updatable items, that would be a good solution.

Comment: Hello, why does it matter whether your service is REST or not? Whatever your code is, service or web site, deploy it to a separate directory on the server, then point IIS to the new location. It doesn't touch the existing requests, but all new requests will now go to the new location.

Comment: If I wanted to build any http service, I'd certainly want a more general answer, but since my goal is specifically a REST service, guidance from someone who had that specific knowledge would be more helpful.

Comment: The two-sites solution is better than what I have now, but I'm shooting for "wicked" (modular, DRY, minimal config) and that a platform that manages the fiddly bits would be optimal.

Answer (score -1):

This is a strange question. First we are in .NET world where assemblies are compiled - this has big impact on other things.

So basically yes you can do what you want if you start programming like PHP programmers. Open your .svc file and write whole your service directly to this file. This is also known as inline coding. You will be able to use types from assemblies deployed to GAC and Bin folder of your site. Just copying the .svc file to your web application directory will make your service available. Modification will also be easy. You have to use .NET 4.0 and you will not need any configuration change when "deploying" new service.

Edit:

Based on comments I'm adding some futher explanation.

IIS and anything dependent on IIS (WAS, AppFabric) always recycle the domain when new assembly is added. I think the reason is directly in .NET core - AppDomain. Loading and unloading assemblies dynamically requires new domain.

Comment: I appreciate the info, I'm want compilation, just of individual assemblies that can then be dropped into a folder and begin serving requests right away without recycling the domain for other assemblies in the same folder.

Comment: I think "COM+" used to be an overwraught attempt at this, services as components that can be updated individually and without interrupting existing requests.